How can i install QuickFIX/J in windows
I've been having a lot of trouble installing QuickFIX/J in my windows computer.
I come here to ask if anybody has done this installation, to share how they did it because I cant figure it out.
.
I tried installing QuickFIX/J in my windows computer.
I've installed Java and Maven and cloned the https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj.git repo but i cant install it.
Thanks!

You can run the example applications that are inside the project - https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/examples.html - https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/tree/master/quickfixj-examples
If you can't build the Java project, you can download the jars from here - https://www.quickfixj.org/downloads/index.html
With the jars, you can run it with java -jar jarfile.jar

QF/j is not an app.  You don't install it.  It's a library.
If you need a better answer, then you need to ask a better question.

Well as far as i know you install libraries, sorry if thats not the correct term. If it is not then please tell me what it is.

It's a library for use in Java applications that you have to write.  Are you a Java programmer?  The way you have phrased your question suggests that you might be misunderstanding what QF/j is for.
